# Facebook Javascript SDK - callback on successful permission request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am just getting acquainted with Facebook javascript SDK.

What is the proper way to check if a permission request was successful then call a function? In my case the user is being requested additional permissions. They have already given basic permissions.

Right now I have this.. but it fires the function regardless of success or not

```
FB.login(function (publishAuth) {
                            if (publishAuth.authResponse) {

                                authSuccess();
                            } else { }
                        }, { scope: 'publish_stream' });
                    }
```

Thanks for the help

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the proper way to check if a permission request was successful then call a function?

Since the user can accept/deny each (extended) permission individually, there is no simple true/false response to a permissions request.

To check, which permissions the user has *actually* granted and which not, you have to make a call to `/me/permissions` – see [Graph API Explorer example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/permissions).

(With field expansion you can do it also in one call while requesting other infos about the user – f.e. [`/me?fields=id,name,permissions`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cpermissions))

Comment: I see what you mean. so for example if I request read_friendslist and publish_stream an the user accepts both, on 'allow' button click will /me/permissions contain those perms to run a conditional against?

Comment: It should contain all possible permissions – permission name as the “key”, and with a value of either 1 or 0, specifying for each permission whether the user granted it or not.

Answer (score 0):

You will always have an authResponse, but that doesn't mean you have the permissions you need, for that you need to check the properties IN the authResponse.

From Facebooks developers page:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
```